# Seeking tool/script to batch save multiple MXD files to map packages

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, map-package

I have a directory and sub-directory with many map documents (MXD). I need to save these MXDs to map packages to send to a client. This can be done through File/Create Map Package.

Are there any tools or scripts that will take all of these MXDs and produce map packages in batch mode, preferably in the background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can write your tool with [Package Map (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000q5000000). and there is a very good example there to use.

> Find and create map packages for all map documents that reside in a
> specified folder.

```
# Author: ESRI

# import system modules
import os
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:/arcgis/ArcTutor/Editing" 

# Loop through the workspace, find all the mxds and create a map package 
  using the same name as the mxd
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print "Packaging " + mxd
    arcpy.PackageMap_management(mxd, os.path.splitext(mxd)[0] + '.mpk', "PRESERVE", 
    "CONVERT_ARCSDE", "#", "ALL")
```

Answer (score 0):

gp's [Package Map tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Package_Map/0017000000q5000000/) combined with python's [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories)