# Creating map package using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, map-package

I'm wondering if there's a way to save a ArcGIS map document (.mxd) as map package file (.mpk) using Python (or even using another programming language)?

I literally have hundreds of .mxd files that I'll need to convert to map package.
If someone has any idea about how to do that, I'd love to know.

Comment: Does this post answer your question?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130939/script-or-code-to-create-map-package-arc-gis-mpk?rq=1

Comment: You could be in for a bit of a shock on this.  Keep in mind that project files (MXD) do not contain any data beyond rules and annotation.  But map packages store the MXD **and** all the data.  So if you have 10GiB in data behind a 100k MXD, you could get a  10-100+GiB map package file (the same table, with several query defs or render rules could be stored multiple times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Python.

```
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\_M92\Desktop\GIS\ArcGIS\Mxd_MattGeo" 

for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    arcpy.PackageMap_management(mxd, os.path.splitext(mxd)[0] + '.mpk')
```

**Note** : Make sure that each of your .mxd(s) has a description in ArcGIS (you can check that by right-clicking on the mxd from the Catalog and choosing Properties/Description). Otherwise, you'll get an [001117 error](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01101-01125-001117.htm).

[image]